# API calls w/ global credentials in Jenkins active choice

Tags: api, jenkins, devops

Is it possible to use the Jenkins credentials set in the global credentials in the active choice plugin groovy script? I'm trying to make an api call that returns a list and display that as a choices for a parameter using the active choice plugin.

But for that I need auth headers w credentials. How do I handle credentials? Is there a way to access them if I have them set up in the Jenkins credentials?
(something like calling credentials(id) in the pipeline env)

Comment: I have been looking into this as well. Ever find if you could do it? I didn't seem to be able to get it working inside the choice script.